# Is there a way to prevent csrf popup form in playframework 2.6

Tags: scala, csrf, playframework-2.6

I work with playFramework 2.6. I have a popup that contains a form. When I try to submit the form, I get the following error:

> Erreur Client!403 - No CSRF token found in body.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: post your form code and application.conf. Also, did you have a read through https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaCsrf

Comment: it's start with @form(CSRF(controllers.workflows.routes.Workflows.updatePhases(0L))) {  //some code here }, all other forms work fine , only popup form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable CSRF folder within `application.conf`:

```
play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter"
```

Then in your form have this:

```
<form action="/submit-form-url" method="POST">
  @CSRF.formField
  //Your form body  
</form>
```

**In case you dont want to use the helper (`@CSRF.formField`)**

First import the required library: `import play.filters.csrf.CSRF`.

Second, get its value within the controller method: `CSRF.getToken` and pass it on the views.

Third, within the views (after the form initial line) use the hidden input to hold the token value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value="whatever-that-is">
```

Comment: Acutally, all other forms work fine, and i added the csrf  like this   @helper.form(CSRF(controllers.admin.routes.Templates.update(0L))) {}, but i don't know why it doesn't work with popup forms.

Comment: @GarraouiMarwen what do you mean by pop up, a modal? Or an actual pop up using JS?  If it is a JS thing you need to pass on the csrf value to the views and use it within the form as an hidden input. I update the answer for this.

Comment: It is a modal wich contain a simple form

Comment: @GarraouiMarwen is a Foundation/Bootstrap modal? I use them every day with no prob. Could you copy/paste your modal code, obviously take out any sensitive data that might contain. Also add your  `application.conf` setting regarding csrf. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Dave Rose, i resolve it by adding the @CSRF.formField inside the form of the modal.

Comment: @GarraouiMarwen awesome! glad I could help.